# How to split or transfer amount to multiple receivers in Paypal?

Tags: paypal

Paypal Adaptive payments unavailable since December 2017. My requirement is that, 97% of the total amount goes to restaurant account and remaining 3% goes to app owner's account. How can i use another one instead of Adaptive payment?

Answer (score 0):

PayPal For Marketplaces was the replacement for Adaptive Payments for select partners.

Below is the information on PayPal For Marketplaces: 
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/marketplaces/pp4mp/

Thanks, 
Jennifer